# Input file path

Tags: jquery, javascript

как получить путь к файлу который выбрал в input file?

```
var fullPath = $('input[type="file"]').val().replace(/.+[\\\/]/, "");                     
            console.log(fullPath);
           $("#imgU").attr({src:fullPath});
```

это возвращает какой-то не такой путь, мне надо сразу вставить в src

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

если надо только имя файла:...

```
<input type="file" class="input">
<div class="block"></div>

$("input:file").change(function (){
  if ($(this).val().lastIndexOf('\\')) {
     var n = $(this).val().lastIndexOf('\\') + 1;
  } else {
     var n = $(this).val().lastIndexOf('/') + 1;
  }
     var fileName = $(this).val().slice(n);
     $(".block").html("<span class='span'>" + fileName + "</span>");
});
```

если надо полный путь то вот:...

```
<input type="file" id="input"/>
<div id="wrap"></div>

$(function() {
  $("#input").change(function (){
     var fileName = $(this).val();
     $("#wrap").html(fileName);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Некоторые браузеры отдаю полный путь, но всё равно его нельзя использовать в качестве src.

Comment: а как быть тогда?

Comment: Например использовать [HTML5 File API][1]

[1]: https://www.google.ru/search?q=HTML5+File+API&oq=HTML5+File+API